# Destacar várias datas com o Calendar View do Android

Tags: android

Meu app registra eventos com data e hora no `sqlite`, tem um menu que mostrará todos esses registros em um calendário, marcando as datas (sem horários) no calendário, como um app de eventos... Quando o usuário clicar na data marcada abrirá uma nova `Activity` mostrando os detalhes desse registro, (data, hora, nome, etc).

Eu consigo setar uma única data com o `setDate(long)` do `CalendarView`, mas como posso setar várias datas?
Ou tem algum meio de marcar as datas que tem algum registro com alguma cor de destaque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procurei e encontrei uma api de terceiros para isso... O calendário dela é bem mais atraente e fácil de usar, pesquisando muito vi que não da para destacar várias datas com o CalendarView do Android...

Crie uma classe que estenda e implementa a classe e interfaces do WeekView:

```
public class ClipperCalendar extends WeekView implements WeekView.EventClickListener, MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener, WeekView.EventLongPressListener, WeekView.EmptyViewLongPressListener {

    private Context context;

    public ClipperCalendar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setOnEventClickListener(this);
        setMonthChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmptyViewLongPress(Calendar time) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "View vazia press: "+time.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventClick(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked " + event.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventLongPress(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "LongPress " + event.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
        // Popular a lista com eventos
        List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();

        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth - 1);
        startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, newYear);
        Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
        endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth - 1);
        WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(1, "Titulo", startTime, endTime);
        event.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
        events.add(event);

        return events;
    }
}
```

Inicialize ela na sua Activity, lembrando que tem que setar o widget no layout:

```
<com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
        android:id="@+id/weekView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:textSize="12sp"
        app:hourHeight="60dp"
        app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
        app:headerColumnTextColor="#8f000000"
        app:headerRowPadding="12dp"
        app:columnGap="8dp"
        app:noOfVisibleDays="3"
        app:headerRowBackgroundColor="#ffefefef"
        app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
        app:todayBackgroundColor="#1848adff"
        app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"/>
```

Inicie o Widget e a classe calendar criada por você:

```
mWeekView = (WeekView) view.findViewById(R.id.weekView);
clipperCalendar = new ClipperCalendar(getContext());
```

Link da API: https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View